# Read script tags in PreRender

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, .net, webforms

I'm trying to work out if its possible to read script tags within the master page PreRender event. I have CSS links working but so far no luck with script tags.

This gets the CSS links:

```
foreach (var c in HeadElement.Controls)
{
    var link = c as HtmlLink;
    if (link != null)
    {
        var url = new Uri(link.Href, UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute);
        if (url.IsAbsoluteUri == false)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(url);
        }
    }
}
```

However, script tags don't seem to be in the control collection, they also aren't in the `ScriptManager.GetCurrent(Page)` Script collection (seems to get the AjaxControlToolkit ScriptManager).

Anyone got any tips please?

FYI they're just normal script tags on the master page, not being added dynamically or with a script manager.

HTML Markup:

```
<head id="HeadElement" runat="server">
   ...
   <link href="/css/normalize.css" rel="stylesheet" />
   <link href="css/jquery.ui.timepicker.css" rel="stylesheet" />
   ...
   <script src="/Scripts/bowser.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
   ...
</head>
```

Comment: Can you post the markup for these css links and script tags?

Comment: If it's just a plain `<script>` tag, without the `runat=server` (which you don't want for scripts), then it's not a control but "plain text" as far as asp.net is concerned.

Comment: That would be annoying if that were the case, the <link> tag hasn't got runat=server either. Oh well, if that's the case so be it. Might have to go through the joy of parsing text :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer to the question:

You can't, WebForms doesn't parse script tags into control objects without having `runat="server"` in them.

Answer to the problem I was trying to solve:

We were having issues with caching, when we released a new version of the site, clients would not get updated.

On our MVC end we are using bundles, which automatically use version URL parameters to force clients to get the latest version. But our legacy WebForms app has script and link tags dotted all over the place so I thought I could get the Master Page to automatically do something similar to what the bundling does.

Reading more into the issue, it can be resolved simply by adding this section into the web.config:

```xml
<system.webServer>
    <staticContent>
        <clientCache cacheControlMode="UseMaxAge" cacheControlMaxAge="00:20:00" />
    </staticContent>
</system.webServer>
```

I set it to 20 minutes as that is our default session timeout length, so should give users relatively good performance through their session (so their browsers won't even request for new content).

After this, their browsers will ping the web server for refreshed content - IIS automatically responds with 304 not modified if necessary so bandwidth isn't drastically affected.